# How to get pseudo from firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-dependencies

I wrote the following model :

```
class UserModelDataUser {

  late final String pseudo;
  late final String email;
  late final String uid;
  //final String uid; //fournit par Firebase
  //UserModel(this.uid);

  UserModelDataUser({
    required this.uid,
    required this.pseudo,
    required this.email,
  });

  set setUid(value) => uid = value;
}

class UserModel {
  late final String theUid;
  UserModel(this.theUid);
}
```

I'm able to get the Uid of my current user : [image]

```
I get this by using Provider : 
...
final user = Provider.of<UserModel?>(context);
final database = DatabaseService(user.theUid);
    return StreamProvider<List<UserModelDataUser>>.value(
      initialData: const [],
      catchError: (_, err) => [],
      value: database.users,
          child: Scaffold(
    ...
user.theUid
...
```

Now, i want to get the pseudo of my user by doing user.pseudo. To do that, i have to change of model (use UserModelDataUser despite UserModel).
But i got difficulties. How can i do this ?
See my DatabaseService :

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import '../models/userModel.dart';
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;

  DatabaseService(this.uid);

  final CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> userCollection =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");

  Future<void> saveUser(String pseudo, String email) async {
    return await userCollection.doc(uid).set({'pseudo': pseudo, 'email': email});
  }

  Future<void> saveToken(String? token) async {
    return await userCollection.doc(uid).update({'token': token});
  }

  UserModelDataUser _userFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.data();
    if (data == null) throw Exception("user not found");
    return UserModelDataUser(
      uid: snapshot.id,
      pseudo: data['pseudo'],
      email: data['email'],
    );
  }

  Stream<UserModelDataUser> get user {
    return userCollection.doc(uid).snapshots().map(_userFromSnapshot);
  }

  List<UserModelDataUser> _userListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return _userFromSnapshot(doc);
    }).toList();
  }

  Stream<List<UserModelDataUser>> get users {
    return userCollection.snapshots().map(_userListFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

Thanks for your time and your help.